# React: relative path doesn't work if importing a script file within public/index.html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, relative-path

I have created my react app using `npx create-react-app`.
So the folder structure is as expected. Like this:

```sh
- public
   - index.html
   - ....
- src
  - App.js
  - ...
```

I am trying to link to a `test.js` from within `index.html`, using a script tag just above `</body>`.
All works well; and if I place that script file in the public folder and put a script tag like this:

```js
<script src="test.js"></script>
```

However, I want to move that script file into the `/src` folder. 
When I do that and try to link to that script file within `index.html` like this:

```js
<script src="../src/test.js"></script>
```

I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` and it is not working either.

Looks like I am missing something very basic. Please help!

Comment: Why are you putting a js file ref defined in 'src' in 'public/index.html'? Is there any specific requirement? if not, avoid doing.

Comment: Your last script tag has a typo, it should be `src` but it's `scr`

Comment: If your question is - Why am I linking to a JS file from within Index.html? - I am using materialize css for my project. Their official documentation recommends this as one of the ways.

Comment: Thanks @SarthakDwivedi. It was a typo here, not in the code. So the error is still intact.

Comment: You may have some code within test.js that has its own relative paths to other imports. I recommend installing the React Dev Tools chrome extension to discover the precise source of the error

Comment: @ThanosDodd, I did check for that. Dumbed down the code in index.html to this - and still the error persists. -- `<p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>

<p id="demo">Click me.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
</script>`

Comment: What happens when you add this `type='text/javascript'`..?

Comment: I added your code from above to the standard html boiler plate code and worked for me!`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>
  <p id="demo">Click me.</p>
  <script>
    document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {
      myFunction()
    };

    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>`

Comment: Did you do `npm start` or similar to run the App?

Comment: @MwamiTovi, nothing changes even if I add the type attribute.

Comment: @ThanosDodd I did run npm start. Also, when you say the code worked for you, did you try to keep the script in a separate file like test.js and then try to run? If I put the script itself in index.html, it runs for me as well. But, that's not what I am after.

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>
  <p id="demo">Click me.</p>
  <script src="../src/test.js">

  </script>

</body>

</html>`

Comment: The above is my index.html. Below is my test.js `document.getElementById("demo").onclick = function() {
  myFunction()
};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}`

Comment: - public
   - index.html
   - ....
- src
  - test.js
  - ...

Comment: @ThanosDodd Beats me. This is exactly what I am doing as well. Just to confirm again, are you also using the boiller plate app created with npx create-react-app?

Comment: Yes. If the code above is the same as yours, the only other thing that could be going wrong, as far as I know, is not cd-ing over to the project directory before 'npm start'. I'd be happy to look at the whole thing if it's on your github or similar

Comment: @ThanosDodd Did not know it mattered from where we fire npm start. Although I checked by firing npm start from both public as well as the parent directory of public and source. No difference. By the way, I tried creating another folder called "scripts" at the same level in the hierarchy as src and public. It works fine if I keep test.js in that folder and reference it as "../scripts/test.js". So the issue is with putting it in src. I don't have my code on github, unfortunately. Pretty new to developing apps still.

Comment: @Rahul where you able to find a fix for this issue?